# After updating child model in knockout my event does not get fired

Tags: knockout.js

My even is fired before I update a child model.  After I have update the child model it the event no longer fires.  The method for updating the model is on a data-bind="click: MyClickFunction"  Inside MyClickFunction the model is passed a new object of CommunityModel and all properties are observables.

```
parentVM.NewPolicy().Community(myCM());
```

after this the even no longer fires.

```
        <input class="column required restrictedAutoComplete mediumInputBox ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
       data-bind="jqAuto: { autoFocus: true, minLength: 0 },
                                        jqAutoSource: viewModel.InitializationValues.ListsOptions.AvailableGrandfatheringTypesArray,
                                        jqAutoValue: viewModel.NewPolicy().Community().GrandfatheringType,
                                        jqAutoSourceLabel: 'Name',
                                        jqAutoSourceInputValue: 'Name',
                                        jqAutoSourceValue: 'ID', valueUpdate: {mouseclick: viewModel.CommunityInfoVM().myAlert() }" placeholder="Grandfathering" />
```

Comment: Can you make a working jsfiddle so someone could step through what is happening.  That is a complex binding statement.

Comment: There is not enough code here to diagnose the issue.